# iad dissapearing on transitionFromView

Tags: ios, objective-c, adbannerview

I have a application that switches between multiple views using `transitionFromView`. when I create a adbanner it only appears on the first view. if I put the adbanner on any view besides the first view, it gives a view hierarchy error. What is the correct method to display a ad on a specific `view` besides the first or to keep the iAd on top of multiple `views`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have added iAd in first `view` of your application. If you want to add iAd in whole application, then you need to add it in `UIWindow`.